# Problem installing thermal printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a usb HOIN HOP-H58 thermal printer that I have not succeeded in installing. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and a POS system that I wish to use the printer with. The system recognises the printer as CUPS-BRF Printer but adding it as such does not work.

Ubuntu system gives these options of adding the printer from the settings:

- By selecting printer name from database - Hoin/Hop not available
- Select a ppd file from installation source -- only .rar file available from
  printer's website: http://hoinprinter.com/en/download
- Installing as Generic (text-only) (still from database of printers) - Does not work

I even tried Epson drivers (As the printer shows something like "command: Espson ESC/POS") but this too was problematic and didn't work.

I will really appreciate any help on how to get the drivers and how to install them ( https://github.com/IntegersOfK/Hoin-POS-58-80 seems to have a probable solution but I could not figure out how to install).

Thanks,
Joseph.

**Hi again...**, I managed to school myself a bit and I "successfully" run the .sh file from the downloaded file. This was the screen output:

### ----------

```
root@User1-job-node:/home/User11/Downloads/Linux Driver/install_package# chmod +x setup58.sh 
root@User1-job-node:/home/User11/Downloads/Linux Driver/install_package# ./setup58.sh
POS Electronics Co..Ltd 
---------------------------------------
    Models included:
                 POS-80-Series
                 POS-58-Series
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Searching for ServerRoot, ServerBin, and DataDir tags in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

ServerBin tag not present in cupsd.conf - using default

DataDir tag not present in cupsd.conf - using default

ServerRoot = 
ServerBin  = 
DataDir    = 

Copying rastertopos58 filter to /usr/lib/cups/filter
chmod: cannot access './bin/rastertopos58': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat './bin/rastertopos58': No such file or directory

Copying model ppd files to /usr/share/cups/model/pos
cp: cannot stat 'ppd/*.ppd': No such file or directory

Add the POS-58-Series printer
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD "/usr/share/cups/model/pos/pos58.ppd": Unable to open PPD file on line 0.
lpadmin: Unable to open PPD file "/usr/share/cups/model/pos/pos58.ppd" - No such file or directory

Restarting CUPS
[ ok ] Stopping cups (via systemctl): cups.service.
[ ok ] Starting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.

Install Complete
Go to http://localhost:631, or http://127.0.0.1:631 to manage your printer please
```

### ----------

**After this, the printer fails to work and the following is noted:**

- Opening http://localhost:631, one cannot "add printer" since after
  entering login details the browser (firefox in this case) searches
  forever with nothing coming out of it,
- The printer ill never print even a testpage and this is shown under 'status' in the    printing preferences for the printer (POS-58-Series): File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rasteropos58" not available: No such file or Directory

***Other tried options for which installation flopped were:***

- https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php
- https://github.com/IntegersOfK/Hoin-POS-58-80

Comment: The line `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file` tells me there was some problem with `packages.tar.gz` and the rest of the script didn't work. The script you ran seems to be for some kind of server. The files and folders the script expects do not exist in your system in the location it expects them.

Comment: Actually this was from local downloaded files - from  https://github.com/IntegersOfK/Hoin-POS-58-80 and http://hoinprinter.com/en/download. Both gave this error. I am not sure though if I should just use 'sudo ./setup58.sh' files on the command-line or there is something I am missing

Comment: I dont know how to install the driver at https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php which seemed a bit complicated (from my searches)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the first line of the script from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, if you get the error, `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file` when running the script.

Instead of running the script, you could also try adding the printer just using the provided PPD file.

- Download the appropriate PPD file (pos58.ppd)
- Plug in your device (USB)
- Open CUPS web interface.
- Addminstration -> 'Add printer'
- Under 'Local Printers', you should see your printer. The generic
  printers usually are displayed as 'Unknown'
- Choose the PPD file from your disk.
- Finally click on 'Add Printer'